# I want a different \ref for \section than the numbering

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, labels, ref

I have the following section numbering

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
```

I introduce a section by

```
\section{Literature Review}\label{sec:lit}
```

and get "II. Literature Review"

Now, when I refer to it by

```
In Section~\ref{sec:lit}, we...
```

the output is "In Section II., we..."

How can I change this to "In Section II, we...". Thus, get rid of the full stop, which I want in the section header but not in the cross-reference.

Example:

```
\documentclass[leqno,letterpaper,12pt,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.} 
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
    Here, we talk about Section~\ref{sec:lit},
    but we do not want the dot after the numbering.

\section{Literature Review}\label{sec:lit}
    This is the literature review.
\end{document}
```

Comment: show a small, but complete example. That makes it much easier to test a solution.

Comment: As you have now noticed, adding the dot to `\thesection` is not a good idea when you don't want it everywhere. Instead learn to configure the look of `\section`. We don't know how the rest of your document (class/preamble) looks to we cannot help you further.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I added a small example.

Comment: I found a solution, working with the titlesec package and changing the titlelabel instead of the numbering. thank you daleif.

Comment: Good. You may choose (not sure if you have enough reputation for it) to answer your own question. Then you'll help others who come by it later on. Another hint: if you use @name for the person you as referring to in a comment, they will be notified. Without it they might never see your comment unless they come back to check up on the comments. Here you'll be notified automatically as you own the item we are commenting on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require loading a package. Instead, it relies on the low-level LaTeX macro `\@seccntformat`, as is explained on page 21 of the book *The LaTeX Companion*, 2nd ed. (The `hyperref` package is loaded below merely to highlight visually what the output of `\ref` consists of.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno,letterpaper,12pt,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
 
\makeatletter % see p. 21 of "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\quad} % section level 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
We talk about Section~\ref{sec:lit}; observe that there is no dot 
(aka ``full stop'') after the Roman numeral.

\section{Literature Review}\label{sec:lit}
This is the literature review.
\end{document}
```